# Output Explanation: A complicated pointer arithmetic

Tags: c, pointers

I have been trying to understand the output of this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>    
int main(){
    static int arr[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    int *p[] = {arr, arr+1, arr+2, arr+3, arr+4};
    int **ptr = p;

    ptr++;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", ptr-p, *ptr-arr, **ptr);
    *ptr++;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", ptr-p, *ptr-arr, **ptr);
    *++ptr;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", ptr-p, *ptr-arr, **ptr);
    ++*ptr;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", ptr-p, *ptr-arr, **ptr);    

    return 0;
}
```

[OUTPUT](http://ideone.com/ZCxci)

```
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
3 4 4
```

Could anybody explain the output?

Comment: In what context do you "encounter" things like these? It just seems contrived, annoying, and horribly pointless to me.

Comment: @unwind:I agree,it also seems `contrived, annoying, and horribly pointless ` but this is one just copied from my question paper.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823808/messy-pointers-killed-me

Comment: Similar: [Pointer *++*ptr use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752549/pointer-ptr-use)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: This is the initial snapshot]

After first ptr++, it would be:
[image]
Hence, `printf("%d %d %d\n",ptr-p,*ptr-arr,**ptr);` will give : 1 1 1

After *ptr++ it will be:[image]
Hence, `printf("%d %d %d\n",ptr-p,*ptr-arr,**ptr);` will give : 2 2 2

After *++ptr, it will be:

[image]

Hence, `printf("%d %d %d\n",ptr-p,*ptr-arr,**ptr);` will give : 3 3 3

After ++*ptr, it will be:

[image]

Hence, `printf("%d %d %d\n",ptr-p,*ptr-arr,**ptr);` will give : 3 4 4

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ptr points to p[1] and p is p[0]. Hence the difference 1. It is the pointer difference.,Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read 6.5.6 in [the C99 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf).

Basically, for difference between pointers

1. they must point within the same array (or one past the end)
2. the difference is the **number of elements** that separate the pointers (or number of bytes divided be size, in bytes, of each element).

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain only the first `printf`. I think it should be enough to understand the rest of printfs. As someone else noticed, the code is based on playing with pointers arithmetics in C language.

`arr` array contains five numbers from 0 to 4.
`p` is an array of pointers to integers and it is filled with "addresses" of the numbers stored in `arr`.
`ptr` is a pointer to a pointer to integer and it is initialized with `p` (because in C language an array of pointers is equivalent to a pointer to a pointer).

Then, `ptr` is incremented. Keep in mind, we are incrementing the address, so now it points to the `(arr+1)` element in `p` array.
That's why `ptr-p` returns 1. In other words, we're subtracting addresses.

`*ptr` points to `arr + 1` element. That's why the second value is also equal to 1.

By doing `**ptr` we retrieve a value that is stored at `arr+1` address and it is also 1.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing to consider is the arithmetic operation on the the pointer.

Do the following ie `add + 1 = add + 1*(size of the data type of the data which is pointed by that address)`

`++` and `--` also like that.