# Runtime error in the following code

Tags: c, runtime-error

The following code,according to me should run successfully,but fails at runtime.I don't get the reason:

```
 void main()
 {
   int arr[5][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
   int *m=arr[0];
   int **p=&m;
   p=p+1;
   printf("%d",**p);

  }
```

a.exe has stopped working at runtime in gcc compiler,windows 7 64 bit

Comment: You may like to read : [double pointer and arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752549/pointer-ptr-use/17752682#17752682)

Comment: Initializing the 2D array is not correct.

Comment: What about all the warnings your are overlooking?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, nice referral, but that answer doesn't deal with 2d arrays.

Comment: @StoryTeller I was unaware that this declaration is wrong!!, Is it true ??

Answer (score 8):

An array of arrays and a pointer to a pointer is quite different, and can't be used interchangeably.

For example, if you look at your array `arr` it looks like this in memory

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----+-----------+
| arr[0][0] | arr[0][1] | arr[0][2] | arr[1][0] | ... | arr[4][2] |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----+-----------+
```

When you have the pointer-to-pointer `p` the program don't really knows that it points to an array of arrays, instead it's treated as an array of pointers, which looks like this in memory:

```
+------+------+------+-----+
| p[0] | p[1] | p[2] | ... |
+------+------+------+-----+
  |      |      |
  |      |      v
  |      |      something
  |      v
  |      something
  v
  something
```

So when you do `p + 1` you get to `p[1]` which is clearly not the same as `arr[1]`.

Comment: Nice answer, from ascii-flow **?**

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Ha ha, nope, still doing it by hand :)

Comment: he also need to answer preferable way to declare and initialized 2d-matrix. I think so.

Comment: +1 I also want to draw pictures like these (while answering of course), though it looks impossible for me to draw with hand ...... are there any tools used for this ??

Comment: @JoachimPileborg,nice answer,thanks,but still don't get why to  int** p=&arr[0] and p=p+1 will not point to arr[1].I thought 4 should be printed as arr[1] will point to arr[1][0].Why I am going wrong?

Comment: @user1369975 When you have an array `arr`, and to `arr + 1` it's the same as `arr[1]`. However `p` *isn't* an array even though it can be treated as one. And when you treat it as an array it's not an array of arrays, but an array of pointers. So while `p` may point to `arr[0][0]` it's treated completely differently. Also, doing `arr + 1` adds `sizeof(int[3])` bytes to `arr`, but `p + 1` adds `sizeof(int*)` bytes to `p`.

Answer (score 4):

With the line

```
int **p=&m
```

you create a pointer to a pointer to an integer.

Then, you add one to the address - one memory address, that is, not one times the number of bytes to point to the next integer.

Then you deference it twice:

- both dereferences will return unspecified values, so the second dereference may break memory boundaries for the OS you are using,
- both times it will be off boundary alignmemnt, which may cause issues in some OSes.

Answer (score 2):

```
int **p=&m;
```

`p` points to address, where `m` is placed:

```
... |  m  | sth | ... |  p  | ...
       ^                 V
       |_________________|
```

Now, increment it:

```
... |  m  | sth | ... |  p  | ...
             ^           V
             |___________|
```

So, now `p` points to `sth`. What is `sth`? Nobody knows. But you're trying to get access to the address `sth` contains. This is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Here `int **p=&m;`. `p` points to `m`. Then when `p = p + 1;` p will point to the address next to `m` (integer). That address may not be accessible.