# What is the difference between these two declarations of array?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

I want to know the difference between theses two declarations of these arrays, one is defined like this (`double array[a][b][c][d]`), the other one is different (`double array[a*b*c][d]`)

```
double weight4_5[LAYER4][LAYER5][LENGTH_KERNEL][LENGTH_KERNEL];
double weight5_6[LAYER5 * LENGTH_FEATURE5 * LENGTH_FEATURE5][OUTPUT];
```

if i want to load values to these two arrays with for loops, how can i do it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between multi dimensional arrays and array of pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823058/difference-between-multi-dimensional-arrays-and-array-of-pointers)

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808535/runtime-error-in-the-following-code and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752549/pointer-expressions-ptr-ptr-and-ptr-use

Comment: They're the same in terms out memory layout. However, the first has the obvious advantage that you can index it more easily.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is a 4 Dimensional array.

- Access is by `weight4_5[i][j][k][l]`

The second one is a 2 Dimensional array. It is a flattened array.

- Access is basically by `weight5_6[x][y]` But you need to do some calculations to get the value of `x` based on the 4D original array.
- You can organise it multiple ways as you want, (e.g. row wise, column wise etc) One way is to have

  ```
  x= ((((i*LAYER5)+j)*LENGTH_FEATURE5)+k)
  y = l;
  ```