# C what does if (!(*dest++ = *src++)) return ret mean?

Tags: c

I'm trying to direct the strncat function. I understand most of it and can write this a diff way, but I can't figure out how to write a longer version of `while (!(*dest++ = *src++))`.

```
char *_strncat(char *dest, char *src, int n)
{
    char *ret = dest;
    while (*dest) /* same as: while (dest[0] !- '\0') */
    {
        dest++; /* w. each loop, array is shifted left until it's empty */
    }
    while (n != 0)
    {
         if (!(*dest++ = *src++)) /* <=========here */
            return ret;
        n--;
    }
    *dest = 0;
    return (ret);
}
```

Can someone show and explain how to expand that line so I can direct it and learn how it works?  Thanks!

Comment: = or == ? I think you have a mistake there ?

Comment: @TonyTannous No, it is intentional. The code is looking for null-terminator

Comment: reverse of null is true

Comment: There's no `while (!(*dest++ = *src++))` in the code. What are you talking about?

Comment: @EugeneSh. So he's assigning the src in dest and once reaching Null he returns.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18481740/4743711 can be of interest for you.

Comment: @dbconfession: Misleading titles damage searchabiity of questions. Titles are not supposed to require "figuring out".

Comment: @AnT fixed the title. thanks

Comment: Note that the `strncat()` uses `size_t`, not `int` --> `char *strncat(char * restrict s1,
const char * restrict s2,
size_t n);`.  If code really used `int`, the loop should be `while (n > 0)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line:

```
if (!(*dest++ = *src++))
    return;
```

can be expanded to:

```
char temp1 = *src++; // copy from *src to temp1 and increment src
char temp2 = (*dest++ = temp1); // Copy temp1 to *dest, increment dest, and also copy value to temp2
if (!temp2) return ret; // return if the value that was copied is a null byte
```

The use of post-increment is important here. It ensures that we copy from `*src` to `*dest` before the pointers are incremented. So to expand it further, it would be:

```
char temp1 = *src;
src = src + 1;
char temp2 = (*dest = temp1);
dest = dest + 1;
if (!temp2)
    return ret;
```

Comment: I think postincrement part should be expanded too as it makes the most confusion as I suspect.

Comment: @Barmar thanks! I'm working through this. When i hit `char temp2 = (dest = temp1);` it returns `error: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversion]
  char temp2 = (dest = temp1);`

Comment: @dbconfession change that line to: `char temp2 = (*dest = temp1);`

Comment: @Barmar Your first expansion output correctly but is failing one unit check. Your second expansion worked AFTER fixing with Aaron's suggestion. If you either fix first or remove it and make aaron's fix in the second expansion I will mark it as answered.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you came back with the information about the unit test tomorrow. I'm not sure what the problem is with my first code.

Comment: The only thing I see with your first example is a missing ; otherwise it should work.

Comment: Thanks @AaronTaggart that's probably what it was.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it is copying the values of `src` into `dest`, incrementing, and then checking for null (or the null terminator). So you could expand it this way:

```
*dest = *src; // Copy the value
if (*dest == '\0') // Was it null?
    return; // We are done!
dest++; // go to next character
src++; // go to next character
```

One point of confusion might be coming from the use of an `=` rather than a `==`. The `=` operator always returns the value that was assigned, this allows for daisy chains of assignment:

```
int a, b, c;
a = b = 0; // sets both a and b to 0
if (c = a) // sets c = a, then performs if(0) which is false.
```

**Note:** 
Technically the `src` and `dest` pointers are incremented even in the case of the return, so this would properly expand to the below, but that is just noise as to understanding what the code is doing:

```
*dest = *src; // Copy the value
if (*dest == '\0') // Was it null?
{
    dest++; // not really needed but happens
    src++; // not really needed but happens
    return; // We are done!
}
dest++; // go to next character
src++; // go to next character
```

Comment: Except that `dest++` and `src++` still happen even if `return` happens.

Comment: So you are correct that src and dest get incremented in that case, but it is a moot point as far as the algorithm is concerned (or understanding how the algorithm works). But I am impressed with that find! I updated the answer.