# changing private data members via pointers is not possible?

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I tried to access a  data member by a pointer, so I write this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class test{
public:
    int * returnAdd();
    int getA();
    void setmember(int x);
private:
    int a;
};

int *test::returnAdd()
{
    return &a;
}

int test::getA()
{
    return a;
} 

void test::setmember(int x)
    {
        a = x;

        return;
    }

int main(void)
{
    test test1;

    int *a = test1.returnAdd();
    test1.setmember(12);
    *a++;
    cout << test1.getA() << endl;
    cout << *a << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I expect that the value of data member (a) would become 13 but it doesn't happen. then I printed the value of *a, and I was garbage.
I wonder why the value of the data member doesn't change, while a is pointing to its location?? and why *a contains garbage and not even a copy of the value of data member a???

Comment: [Recommended read](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18484907/7571258). He explains pretty good what expression `*a++` (aswell as variants `*++a` and `++*a`) actually do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*a++;` doesn't mean:

1. Dereference `a`
2. Increment it (what is pointed at by `a`)

`*a++;` means:

1. Dereference `a`
2. Increment the pointer `a`

Use `(*a)++;` to increment what is pointed at.

Answer (score 4):

As a result of [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), The post increment operator `++` is executed before `a` is dereferenced. Hence the original expression `a`, returned by the [post increment operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445706/post-increment-and-pre-increment-concept) is dereferenced.

Meanwhile `a` is incremented to point to the next non-existent adjacent memory. The next time you dereference `a` will invoke Undefined Behavior.

You probably wanted:

```
(*a)++;
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb9a11b8efc98953)

Comment: _Hence you moved a to the next non-existent adjacent memory, then dereferenced it. Which invoked Undefined Behavior._ ... is not correct. The effect of `*a++` is that the pointer `a` is first dereferenced and then incremented. This [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd98eb9e73f3da42) prints "1" then "2". If your statement were correct, it would print "2" and then "2" again. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18484907/7571258) for a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You are moving a pointer, then reading from it. Try `(*a)++;`

Answer (score -2):

It is private so you want to get It

Try to write a member function that does that for you

```
void test::add_one(void)
{
++a;
}
```

Always look for the easy way 
Hope this helps

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.