# Difference in Call by Reference Vs Call by pointer argument todo pre and postincrement

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, post-increment, pre-increment, pass-by-pointer

I know how to do call by reference and call by pointer operations. But I am confused about doing both of them in pre and post-increment operation. Here the code snippet.

**Call by reference with pointer arguments**

```
void fun2(int *x) // It works like int *x=&x;
{
    ++*x;  // *x++ does not provide lvalue, so will not work here [ I think So ]
}
```

**Call by reference with reference arguments**

```
void fun3(int& x)
{
    ++x;  // x++; [both works fine but I can't understand why?]
}
```

**Here's the Driver code**

```
int main()
{
    int x=10;
    cout<<x<<"\n"; //10
    fun2(&x);
    cout<<x<<"\n"; //11
    fun3(x);
    cout<<x<<"\n"; //12
    return 0;
}
```

Why in fun2() *x++ gives the output 10 instead of giving 11 but ++*x works fine and in fun3() both x++ and ++x works fine?

Comment: Sorry while asking here I mistyped it. No, while writing code  I write it fine void fun3(int &x). But don't know why call-by-pointer *x++ not changing the value of x

Comment: See the linked duplicate. It is about C (I am still trying to find a good C++ duplicate.) but it applies exactly the same to C++.

Comment: See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481740/pointer-expressions-ptr-ptr-and-ptr

Comment: Thank you, That's exactly what I'm asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pointer expressions: \*ptr++, \*++ptr and ++\*ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481740/pointer-expressions-ptr-ptr-and-ptr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `fun2()`, `*x++` does not do what you think it does.

Per [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), the `++` **postfix increment** operator has a higher precedence than the `*` dereference operator. As such, the statement `*x++` is treated as `*(x++)`, incrementing the pointer before then dereferencing it. The value being pointed at is untouched.

For what you are expecting, you need to use `(*x)++` instead, dereferencing the pointer and then incrementing the value being pointed at.

You don't have the same problem with 
`++*x` because the `++` **prefix increment** operator has the same precedence as the `*` dereference operator but is evaluated first, so `++*x` is treated as `++(*x)`.

In `func3()`, there is no pointer to dereference. `x` is a reference to the caller's `int` (`x` in `main()`), and so both increment operators are being invoked directly on that `int`.