# Understanding dereferencing of double pointers

Tags: c, string, pointers, double-pointer

Here is a predict the output program asked in my recent online test. I was unable to get the accurate output because I am not familiar with double pointers dereferencing. I am aware of the precedence order and the side effects of postfix operation which plays a vital in understanding pointer questions.

Kindly help me with this code snippet by giving examples of double-pointer dereferencing.
For more info on single-pointer dereferencing here is a very helpful answer:
[Pointer expressions: *ptr++, *++ptr and ++*ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481740/pointer-expressions-ptr-ptr-and-ptr)

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main()

    {
        char *a[] = {"NITK", "SURATH", "KALMAN", "GALO", "BREAK", "REJOIN"};
        char **b[] = {a + 2, a + 3, a, a + 1, a + 5, a + 4};
        char ***c = b;
        *c++;
        printf("%s\t", *++*c);
        printf("%s\t", **c + 2);
        printf("%c", (*(**(c + 2) + 2) + 2));
        return 0;
    }
```

Expected output:

```
BREAK EAK T
```

P.s This question might not have a practical use, but it will be helpful to understand the concept of double pointers.

Comment: avoid this kind of expressions. They do not have any practical use. Actually if I see something like this doing the code review - I ask to rewrite the whole thing.

Comment: Agree with @P__J__, but this question is from a test.

Comment: I agree with @P__J__. As I mentioned this question is from a test, I just wanted to clear my concept of double-pointer dereferencing.

Comment: regarding: `char ***c = b;` [three star programmer](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Comment: it is easiest to read an expression, like: `*++*c` from right to left.  Which results in: variable c is a pointer  preincrement that pointer, dereference that pointer.  However, must pay attention to the precedence of the operators, so the `++` will be done first then the two dereferences.  Suggest reading [C precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters it is a very silly test. Ignore firms that give such a test with obfuscated code. Do not deal with idiots. Usually such tests are given by low-qualified programmers.

Take into account that an array designator used in expressions with rare exceptions is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element.

So this declaration

```
char ***c = b;
```

is equivalent to

```
char ***c = &b[0];
```

In this expression statement

```
*c++;
```

the dereferenced value of the pointer is not used. So this statement should be written like

```
c++;
```

After this statement the pointer `c` points to the second element of the array `b`.

You could rewrite the statement above like

```
c = &b[1];
```

Now let's consider the expression in the printf call

```
printf("%s\t", *++*c)
```

Dereferencing the pointer `c` you get lvalue `b[1]` that has the value `a + 3`. Applying the unary operator ++ to this expression you will get `a + 4`. And at last dereferencing this expression you will get the lvalue `a[4]`
that is outputted.

```
BREAK
```

Now consider the expression in the second call of printf.

```
printf("%s\t", **c + 2);
```

Dereferencing the pointer `c` the first time you will get the lvalue `b[1]`. After the first call of printf it contains the value `a + 4`. Dereferencing this expression you get the lvalue a[4] that points to the string literal "BREAK". Adding 2 the pointer expression will point to the third character of the string literal. So there will be outputted

```
EAK
```

At last let's consider the expression in the third call of printf.

```
printf("%c", (*(**(c + 2) + 2) + 2));
```

As c points to b[1] then using the pointer arithmetic `c + 2` the expression will point to `b[3]` Dereferencing the pointer you will get the lvalue `b[3]` that contains the value `a + 1`. Dereferencing this expression you will get the lvalue `a[1]` that points to the string literal `"SURATH"`. Again applying the pointer arithmetic you will get a pointer that points to the third element of the string literal that is to the sub string `"RATH"`. Dereferencing the pointer expression you will get the character `'R'`. Addi g to the character the value 2 you will get the character 'T' that is outputted

```
T
```

That is all.

Answer (score 1):

1. `*c++;` it should be `c++;` as `*` does not have anny effect here. after this operation it references reference to second value of the double pointer array `b` (`a + 3`)
2. After dereference it points to pointer to pointer to `a+3` it is increased (so it references pointer to `a + 4`. Another dereference gives pointer to `a + 4`
3. As previous operations made `c` to reference pointer to pointer to to `a + 4`, the `**c` references `a + 4` so the **c + 2 references the third character of `a + 4`.
4. `c + 2` is a pointer to pointer to `a + 1`.  Then ** references the the `a + 1`. Adding 2 to it references the third character of `a + 1` which is `R`. dereferencing this pointer gives char `'R'`. Add 2 to it and you get `'T'` assuming the ASCII char encoding.