# Right to left associativity with pointers

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, char

I'm currently learning about pointers in C, but I'm a little confused about how right to left associativity works with regards to incrementing a pointer versus incrementing the value being pointed at.

It is understood that ++ and * are both right to left associative in C.

I don't see how `*s++` moves the array ahead 1, yet `(*s)++` increments the value being pointed at but doesn't move the array ahead.

For example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char c[20] = "Help";
    char *s;
    s = c; 
    printf("init: %s\n",s); // Help
    ++*s;
    printf("++*s: %s\n",s); // "Ielp" ascii increment of first element
    ++(*s);
    printf("++(*s): %s\n",s); // "Jelp" ascii increment of first element
    *s++;
    printf("*s++: %s\n",s); // "elp" moves to next element in array
    (*s)++;
    printf("(*s)++: %s\n",s); // "flp" ascii increment of current element
    *(++s);
    printf("*(++s)\n: %s\n",s); // "lp" moves to next element
    *++s;
    printf("*++s\n: %s\n",s); // "p" moves to next element
    return 0;
}
```

For the code above, can someone help explain what is going on **AND** why?

*Thanks for taking a look.*

Comment: Associativity only matters when no parentheses are present. When they are, expressions in parentheses are always evaluated first. Similar reason why `7-3+2=6` but `7-(3+2)=2`.

Comment: Also, `*s++` evaluates to `*(s++)` not because of associativity, but because the postfix increment `++` has strictly [higher precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than the dereference `*` operator.

Comment: Voting to close as a duplicate of [Pointer expressions: \*ptr++, \*++ptr and ++\*ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481740/pointer-expressions-ptr-ptr-and-ptr) which has several detailed answers.

Comment: Thanks @dxiv! The first answer on that question is the perfect explanation. For whatever reason google and SO search wouldn't reveal that great explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As helped by dxiv and John Bode,

> When parsing an expression, an operator which is listed on some row will be bound tighter (as if by parentheses) to its arguments than any operator that is listed on a row further below it. For example, the expression *p++ is parsed as *(p++), and not as (*p)++.

In the above expression the point worth noted is `++` is a postfix operator whose precedence(or priority) is greater than `*`(unary operator)

> Operators that are in the same cell (there may be several rows of operators listed in a cell) are evaluated with the same precedence, in the given direction. For example, the expression a=b=c is parsed as a=(b=c), and not as (a=b)=c because of right-to-left associativity.

other example where associativity comes into picture is `*++p`

here `*` and `++`(prefix operator) are having same precedence, so they will be evaluated as right to left.

Comment: The right-to-left associativity plays no role into why `*s++` is being evaluated as `*(s++)`. That follows from the precedence of the operators alone.

Comment: @dxiv, but [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) `*` and `++` have same precendece , am i wrong?

Comment: Also there is para there saying _Operators that are in the same cell (there may be several rows of operators listed in a cell) are evaluated with the same precedence, in the given direction. For example, the expression a=b=c is parsed as a=(b=c), and not as (a=b)=c because of right-to-left associativity._

Comment: In the table at your link, *postfix* `++` has precedence 1, lower than precedence 2 for the dereference `*` operator. In fact that's precisely the example given at that link, read the paragraph "*when parsing an expression ...*" below the table.

Comment: @IrAM: *Prefix* `++` has the same precedence as unary `*`, so `*++p` is affected by associativity.  Postfix `++` has higher precedence than unary `*`, so `*p++` is evaluated as `*(p++)` irrespective of associativity.

Comment: @JohnBode, yeah got it, got little confused there

Comment: @IrAM Thanks for the explanation. I also learned from the discussion here in the comments. Marking as correct.

Comment: All credit goes to @dxiv and JohnBode