# Does a 2's complement with increment violate order of execution rules in c++17 but not c++14?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14, order-of-execution

This is probably "[c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) 101" level question but there is some associated pain so I will ask for comments to be confident.

I have some legacy code to support going back to [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) and before with this line:

```
iTmp = ~iTmp++;
```

This worked 100% until the code was changed to [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17). After changing to [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) it then calculated a different value, but not always. It depends on where the line is in code whether it executes the 2's complement first or the increment first.

Also, if you try to force with parenthesis it is a compiler error:

```
iTmp = (~iTmp)++;

error C2105: '++' needs l-value
```

This makes sense to me because the 2's complement result is not an intermediate variable so the ++ has nothing to operate on.

My research tells me that

1. this is an "[order-of-execution](/questions/tagged/order-of-execution)" failure.
2. [operator-precedence](/questions/tagged/operator-precedence) is not the primary cause of failure for this case.
3. two's complement is not an in-place operation so it does not change iTmp but instead returns a value.
4. the legacy code worked by shear luck - probably due to a compiler bug or mistake which always enforced an operator evaluation order.

Is my evaluation correct?

It is to me a very subtle difference that the previous code is invalid but this line is OK:

```
if ( ++iTmp > 0)
```

I did not expect an upgrade to [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) to cause this subtle error but I had to change the code to the following to solve the problem:

```
iTmp = ~iTmp;
iTmp++;
```

Comment: "both operators are binary." Both operators are unary. Postfix increment has higher precedence than unary `~`, so it should be interpreted as `iTmp = ~(iTmp++);`

Comment: casually, there is no need to rely on this sort of contrived confusion in code if you know how it should behave!

Comment: *"operator precedence does not get involved because both operators are...."* **Why do you think so? Whether an operator is unary or binary has no effect on precedence.**

Comment: In C++14, the line was **undefined behavior** (because it was *unsequenced*).  In C++17, the behavior is defined.

Comment: Also, don't write code like this as it can have surprising(if not undefined) result/behavior. Also see [Pointer expressions: *ptr++, *++ptr and ++*ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481740/pointer-expressions-ptr-ptr-and-ptr)

Comment: looking at [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) one can see, that post increment `++` has higher precedence than `~` and should thus be applied first, but because `iTmp++` is post increment, its result it is just `iTmp` from before, thus the increment has no effect.

Comment: *the legacy code worked by shear luck - probably due to a compiler bug* -- If you are not ready to demonstrate it is a compiler bug by quoting the C++ standard, you should not assume it is a compiler bug.

Comment: The complement is not relevant to your problem. Mixing postincrement and assignment to the same variable is: https://godbolt.org/z/GMKcrMxP9

Comment: [What are the evaluation order guarantees introduced by C++17?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501587/what-are-the-evaluation-order-guarantees-introduced-by-c17)

Comment: Beware of the nomenclature. "2's complement" is a way to represent negative values in binary. It is created by taking a value, negating all bits and finally adding 1 to result. `~` is only negating all the bits - that's one's complement.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen is correct.  Two's complement is spelled `-x` (guaranteed for unsigned types and it's also two's complement for signed types on most platforms), not `~x`.

Comment: @teapot418 g++ makes an incorrect diagnosis in `-std=c++17` (and later). clang++ does not. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/8zqKonrEG)

Comment: This is quite an engaging topic, still, it seems.  Even though C++17 has been around for many years now, I wouldn't be surprised if legacy code that "worked" suddenly breaks when big projects now starting to go C++17 and beyond.

Comment: My description was not precise enough I think. I suspected that the issue was 100% bad code when I discovered the changed behavior but when I commented "compiler bug" what I meant was it was undefined behavior but it behaved consistently, giving the same result after each compilation and moving forward through several c++ version but finally behaving inconsistently with c++17.

Comment: @visualbill "_it was undefined behavior but it behaved consistently_": That's not unexpected for undefined behavior. Undefined behavior means that there is _no guarantee_ on the behavior. There is no guarantee that it will work consistently the same way each time you try and there is no guarantee that it won't either. There is also no guarantee that it won't work seemingly consistent the whole time until you change the compiler, compiler version or compiler flags or make any other change.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> This worked 100% until the code was changed to c++17.

It has undefined behavior before C+17, because there are two side effects on `iTmp` (one incrementing and one assigning) and neither `=` nor the post-increment implied any sequencing between these two side effects.

It seems you just were lucky that the compiler always compiled it in a way that behaves as you wanted it to.

> After changing to c++17 it then calculated a different value, but not always.

No, since C++17 it is clearly defined: The right-hand side of the assignment is completely evaluated first, i.e. `iTmp` is first incremented. However, `iTmp++` produces the previous value of `iTmp` and that value computation is also sequenced before the assignment's side effect. Therefore it will behave equivalent to `iTmp = ~iTmp`, except that it will also have UB if `iTmp` is signed and overflows by the increment.

[Refining Expression Evaluation Order for
Idiomatic C++](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0145r3.pdf)

> It depends on where the line is in code whether it executes the 2's complement first or the increment first.

I don't know what you mean here. There is no choice anymore for the compiler. Only one order is correct.

> Also, if you try to force with parenthesis it is a compiler error:

Yes, because you can't increment a rvalue (which the `~` operator produces).

> This makes sense to me because the 2's complement result is not an intermediate variable so the ++ has nothing to operate on.

The term "intermediate variable" does not exist in C++. The reason is that the expression is not a lvalue. That's just a somewhat arbitrary choice of the language specification. It avoids making mistakes.

If `(~iTmp)++` was allowed, then it would mean that you first create a new integer object with the value of `~iTmp`, which exists only temporary, then increment that temporary. After the expression the temporary is destroyed again. A behavior like that is likely not intended, because the value of the temporary object won't matter later and if you only wanted to read its value before it is destroyed in the expression then you could have written `(~iTmp) + 1` instead, which is much clearer and less confusing.

> this is an "order-of-execution" failure.

Yes.

> operator-precedencedoes not get involved because both operators are binary.

Operator precedence is relevant because you need to be able to parse that `~iTmp++` is `~(iTmp++)`, not `(~iTmp)++`. Note that this is only about parsing. It doesn't affect order of evaluation. I don't know why you think that binary operators somehow don't imply relevance of operator precedence.

> two's complement is not an in-place operation so it does not change iTmp but instead returns a value.

"*two's complement*" is a representation choice of signed integer values in a set of bits. The operator `~` is just the *complement* and it doesn't matter what the representation choice for the integer type is. Also yes, `~` doesn't modify `iTmp`.

> the legacy code worked by shear luck - probably due to a compiler bug or mistake which always enforced an operator evaluation order.

Yes, it worked by luck. But the compiler is not to blame at all. The code was simply wrong.

> It is to me a very subtle difference that the previous code is invalid but this line is OK:

There is only one modification of `iTmp` in that line. It is vitaly important to know and understand the order of evaluation rules in C++ and when they cause undefined behavior, e.g. if two side effects or one side effect and a value computation are unsequenced.

See [cpprference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) for a reference on the order of evaluation rules, although that might be a bit overwhelming as an introduction. Any introductory book to C++ should go over the basic order of evaluation rules in a more approachable manner. Otherwise a newcomer to C++ is eventually going to write dangerous code as in your example.

> I did not expect an upgrade to c++17 to cause this subtle error but I had to change the code to the following to solve the problem:

Yes, that's fine and doesn't violate the general rule one should follow: In every expression modify each object at most once.

Comment: I hope I didn't mess it up, but that's the link I added was what I was planning to build an answer around until you answered :-)

Answer (score 0):

> I have some legacy code with this line: `iTmp = ~iTmp++;`

Prior to C++17, the sequencing of the side-effect of postfix increment `++` was unspecified.

1. Should it happen after the entire expression has been evaluated, and the semi-colon is encountered at the end of the expression?
2. Or should it happen after the subexpression `~iTmp++` has been evaluated, but before the assignment occurs?

Because the order was unspecified by the C++ Standard prior to C++17, your compiler was free to choose option 1, which, evidently, it did.

Under C++17, the sequencing is specified by option 2.

Assignment is one of the examples in the paper by [Gabriel Dos Reis, Herb Sutter, and  Jonathan Caves](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0145r3.pdf), which describes the changes made in C++17. In the expression `b = a`, the subexpression `a` must be fully evaluated, including side-effects, prior to the evaluation of subexpression `b`.

Thus, the expression statement `iTmp = ~iTmp++;` is evaluated in this sequence:

1. *Postfix increment:* `iTmp++` gives the result `iTmp`, with the increment being deferred until all of the subexpression `~iTmp++` (i.e., subexpression `a`) is complete.
2. *One's complement:* The value of `~iTmp` is computed as the result of `~iTmp++`. This is the value that will be assigned to subexpression `b` in step 4.
3. *Side effect applied:* The value of `iTmp` is incremented. This value will be overwritten in step 4.
4. *Assignment:* `iTmp` is assigned the value calculated in step 2.