# Pointers and Arrays: pointer to pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I am not getting how the following thing is working?

```
void main()
{
    static int a[] = {10, 12, 23, 43, 43};
    int *p[] = {a, a + 1, a + 2, a + 3, a + 4};
    int **ptr = p;
    ptr++;
    printf("%d,%d,%d", ptr - p, *ptr - a, **ptr);
}
```

This is giving the output as `1 1 10`. I get that `**ptr` gives the value stored at `ptr` but why is `ptr-p` giving `1` should it not give `sizeof(int)`?

Comment: Please provide code that passes compilation.

Comment: @Evgeny is right, this code should not compile, so your question is moot

Comment: have a look at pointer arithmetic http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html

Comment: @Evgeny sorry for the error, i have corrected it now.

Comment: Read [Pointer expressions: **ptr++, *++*ptr and ++**ptr use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752549/pointer-expressions-ptr-ptr-and-ptr-use/17752682#17752682)

Comment: Arrays are still not pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To explain output I commented the of code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                 

int main()                                                                                                         
{                                                                                                                  
   // a is an array of integers                                                                                    
   static int a[]={10, 12, 23, 43, 43};                                                                            

   // p is an array of integer pointers. Each of the element, holds address of elements in array "a"               
   // p[0] = &a[0], p[1] = &a[1], p[2] = &a[2], p[3]=&a[3], p[4]=&a[4]                                             
   int *p[]={a, a + 1, a + 2, a + 3, a + 4};                                                                       

   // ptr is a pointer to an integer pointer. Ptr holds base address of array "p"                                  
   // ptr = &p[0]                                                                                                  
   // *ptr = *(&p[0]) = p[0]                                                                                       
   // **ptr = *(p[0]) = *(&a[0]) = a[0] = 10                                                                       
   int **ptr = p;                                                                                                  

   // ptr was pointing to zeroth element in the p array, which is p[0].                                            
   // Incrementing pointers, makes it to move by X bytes and hence point to the next element.                      
   // where X = sizeof(int *). int* is p's datatype.                                                               
   ptr++;                                                                                                          

   // ptr = &p[1]                                                                                                  
   // *ptr = *(&p[1]) = p[1]                                                                                       
   // **ptr = *(p[1]) = *(&a[1]) = a[1] = 12                                                                       

   // pointer difference is measured by the number of elements                                                     
   // since ptr points to p+1. difference is 1                                                                     
   printf("ptr - p: %p\n", (void*)(ptr - p) );                                                                     

   // ptr holds address of p+1. *ptr holds value of p[1], which as explained in the above holds address of a[1].   
   // Hence difference of (a+1) - a is 1                                                                           
   printf("*ptr - a: %p\n", (void* )(*ptr - a));                                                                   

   // ptr holds address of p+1. *ptr holds address of a[1]. **ptr holds value of a[1].                             
   printf("**ptr: %d\n", **ptr);                                                                                   
   return 0;                                                                                                       
}
```

Have printf statements and validate the comments I have provided in the program for better understanding.

For Example.  Compare `p[0]` and `&a[0]`. Compare `*p[3]` and `a[3]`.

Hope the code and the comments help you.

Provided code is compilable and output on my screen is

```
ptr - p: 0x1
*ptr - a: 0x1
**ptr: 12
```

Comment: Very nice explanation, I would like to suggest don't put useful statements as comment. explain point to point in main section.

Comment: Also in your text you should codify programing terms using `<code>` Write: `"Compare <code>p[0]</code> and <code>&a[0]</code>. Compare <code>*p[3]</code> and <code>a[3]</code>."`

Answer (score 2):

In pointer arithmetic, `ptr - p` will output the **number** of elements from `p` to `ptr`, not the **size** from `p` to `ptr`. The size of elements is not relevant.

BTW, your code doesn't compile. A minimal example to illustrate your question looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    static int a[] = {10,12,23,43,43};
    int *p = a;
    int *ptr = p;
    ptr++;
    printf("%p %p %d\n", (void*)ptr, (void *)p, ptr - p);
    return 0;
}
```

Output on my machine:

```
0x600b44 0x600b40 1
```

Comment: Maybe even `printf("%p %p %d\n",ptr,p,ptr-p);` to demonstrate the addresses' difference *and* the arithmetic difference.

Comment: @glglgl That's better, I'll use that :)

Answer (score 1):

Pointer arithmetic is done using the size of the element pointed to. Since you used `++` on `ptr`, the difference is going to be `1` no matter what type `ptr` is.