# Incrementing Pointers

Tags: c, pointers

Consider this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double *dp;
    double **dpp;

    dpp=&dp;

    dp++;
    dpp++;

   return 0;    
}
```

Suppose `dp` has address 100 and `dpp` has address 1000.
What will the address of these pointers be after incrementing?

Comment: Just run, print the values, and see for yourself.

Comment: @ ValekHalfHeart how can i assign initial address of 100 and 1000 to dp and dpp

Comment: Whenever you're using a pointer, make sure it is initialized.  You need `double d[2];` and `double *dp = d;` or thereabouts to make your code `dp++;` reliable and describable.  In fact, you also need similar treatment for `dpp` too.  At the moment, `dp++` could generate a fault (it does invoke undefined behaviour), and `dpp` doesn't point to anywhere determinate after the increment.

Comment: @Sarao You dont have to initialize the values as 100 and 1000 resp..Just print the values before and after incrementing the pointers..You will know the difference...

Comment: Read [Pointer expressions: `**ptr++`, `*++*ptr` and `++**ptr` use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752549/pointer-expressions-ptr-ptr-and-ptr-use) It uses pointer to pointer increments

Answer (score 3):

The simplest thing is to make your program compilable and give it strictly defined behaviour, then run it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double   d[2]   = { 3.141593, 2.718128 };
    double  *dp     = &d[0];
    double  *dpa[2] = { &d[0], &d[1] };
    double **dpp    = dpa;

    printf("dp  = %p\n", (void *)dp);
    printf("dpp = %p\n", (void *)dpp);
    dp++;
    dpp++;
    printf("dp  = %p\n", (void *)dp);
    printf("dpp = %p\n", (void *)dpp);

    return 0;
}
```

Note how the code carefully ensures that the pointers always point to valid data.  You could extend the printing to print `*dpp` (another pointer) and `**dpp` and `*dp` (both double values).

On my machine (Mac OS X 10.9.1, GCC 4.8.2, 64-bit compilation), the output is:

```
dp  = 0x7fff56945510
dpp = 0x7fff56945520
dp  = 0x7fff56945518
dpp = 0x7fff56945528
```

When compiled for 32-bit, the output is:

```
dp  = 0xbfffc600
dpp = 0xbfffc5f0
dp  = 0xbfffc608
dpp = 0xbfffc5f4
```

The jump of 8 in `dp` is a consequence of `sizeof(double) == 8` (for both 32-bit and 64-bit compilations).  The change in `dpp` of 4 for the 32-bit compilation and 8 for the 64-bit compilation is a consequence of `sizeof(double *) == 4` for 32-bit and `sizeof(double *) == 8` for 64-bit.

Answer (score 2):

`dp++` is undefined behavior, since `dp` was never initialized. There are no guarantees about what will happen.

What will *probably* happen, though relying on this would be a poor decision, is that the numerical value in memory of `dp` is incremented by `sizeof(double)`, and the numerical value of `dpp` is incremented by `sizeof(double *)`. `sizeof(double)` is probably 8, and `sizeof(double *)` is probably 4 or 8.

Comment: @ user 2357112 how can i assign address of 100 to dp in c program

Comment: @Sarao: While you can sort of do that, it's also undefined behavior, so it's not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

`double *dp` => is pointer to variable of type double (size of `dp` is 4 bytes only)

`double **dp1` => is a pointer to pointer which is pointing to double (size of `dp1` is 4 bytes)

Pointer's size is always 4 bytes (assuming 32-bit machine; on a 64-bit machine, it's 8 bytes)
i.e pointer size depends on how big the memory address is.

When you increment `dp++`, you increment pointer pointing to double whose size is 8 bytes so it increments by 8 bytes (100 => 108).

When you increment the pointer to pointer, its size is 4 bytes so it increments by 4 bytes only (1000 => 1004)

Pointer increments depend on the type of object it is pointing at.

In your code you haven't declared a variable of type `double` directly; you have initialized `**dp1` which will will result in undefined behavior.

```
double a = 10.00;
dp = &a;
```

add the above two line to understand your code better (just one of the way).