# difference between *p++ and *p++=*q

Tags: c

in this code, if I write " *p++=*q " instead of " *p++ " nothing changes. Why?

```
int a[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int *p=a, *q=&a[8];

*p++;

printf("%d  \n", *p);
printf("%d  \n", *q);
printf("%d  \n", p);
printf("%d  \n", q);
```

Comment: Note: `printf("%d  \n", p);` --> UB.

Comment: What do you expect to change and why?

Comment: if I write `printf("%d  \n", *(p + 0));`, nothing changes, think why...

Comment: Something changes. You just don't see what changes because you don't look at it.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: UB isn't major issue here !!!

Comment: `*p++;` should trigger a compiler warning. It's equivalent to `p++` because you're not using the result of dereferencing.

Comment: You'd better learn about pointers and string formatting. Here on SO we'd assume you wouldn't need to.

Comment: `*p++` = increment the pointer `(*p)++` = increment what is pointed

Comment: @Destructor since you've raised the topic, let me tell you, UB is the MAJOR issue anywhere. Any code, having UB cannot be trusted to don anything sane at all.

Comment: Your code invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: I wish you good luck, with this attitude you will need lots of it.

Comment: @n.m. apparently not, some or other will be there to _help_ (sadly). I don't understand one thing, why do some people forget _who_ came here asking for _halp_. :)

Comment: read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752549/pointer-expressions-ptr-ptr-and-ptr-use/17752682#17752682)

Comment: I got it now, thank you very much @GrijeshChauhan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*p++;` means

1. increment `p` and get its value before incrementing
2. dereference the value
3. throw the result away

`*p++=*q;` means

1. increment `p` and get its value before incrementing
2. dereference the value to know where to store
3. dereference `q`
4. store the data read

(the actual order of evaluation is unspecified and may differ)

Changing it do changes. You didn't observe the change because you didn't check the value stored in `p[-1]` (`p` is value after incrementing).

Note that the lines

```
printf("%d  \n", p);
printf("%d  \n", q);
```

invoke *undefined behavior* by passing data having wrong value to `printf`. The lines should be

```
printf("%p  \n", (void*)p);
printf("%p  \n", (void*)q);
```

Use `%p` specifier and cast the pointer to print to `void*` to print pointers via `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is wrong. You claim "nothing changes" and ask why.

The reality is that *something* changed. But not any of the things you were looking at. Go and figure out what changed.

On top of that, printing p and q with a %d modifier is undefined behaviour.

I have £5 in my wallet. I put £10 in my sock. I check my wallet, and there is still £5 in my wallet. Nothing changed. Why?

Comment: Unless you say what *did* change, this is better as a comment (and in fact you did post it as a comment, so why post the non-answer too?).

Comment: A logically valid question can be still be based on an incorrect assumption, IMHO, @alk